# readlink not working when parameters is surrounded with double quote

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to locate the real path of the running script , but when `$0` was in some folders that contains space , `readlink` would fail , so i surrounded $0 with `"` , but readlink ceased to work this time.

```
  RPATH="$(readlink -f \"$0\")"
  echo $RPATH
```

Thanks , and if bash itself can do this , it's much more better !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't escape the inner quotes. As it is, they are handled to readlink as part of the filename (instead of preventing word splitting).

Comment: Apart from that, you don't need quotes around an assignment value, but that is cosmetic.